# ListPlot3D doesn't work but ListPointPlot3D does (Mathematica)

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, 3d

The code below works, but when I replace the ListPointPlot3D with ListPlot3D it doesn't work!

This works:

```
ListPointPlot3D[Transpose[Table[{i,j, (150*(Sin[((i - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)* (Sin[((j - 45)*2*3.14)/180]^2)) - 150}, {i, 0, 270, 5}, {j, 0, 270, 5}]]]
```

This doesn't work:

```
ListPlot3D[Transpose[Table[{i,j, (150*(Sin[((i - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)* (Sin[((j - 45)*2*3.14)/180]^2)) - 150}, {i, 0, 270, 5}, {j, 0, 270, 5}]]]
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work??

Answer (score 6):

Your data:

```
In[1]:= Dimensions[
 Transpose[
  Table[{i, 
    j, (150*(Sin[((i - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)*(Sin[((j - 45)*2*3.14)/
           180]^2)) - 150}, {i, 0, 270, 5}, {j, 0, 270, 5}]]]

Out[1]= {55, 55, 3}
```

But [ListPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot3D.html) wants a list of triples, so [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html) 1 level:

```
ListPlot3D[
 Flatten[Transpose[
   Table[{i, 
     j, (150*(Sin[((i - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)*(Sin[((j - 45)*2*3.14)/
            180]^2)) - 150}, {i, 0, 270, 5}, {j, 0, 270, 5}]], 1]]
```

The Transpose is therefore redundant so this will do:

```
ListPlot3D[
 Flatten[Table[{i, 
    j, (150*(Sin[((i - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)*(Sin[((j - 45)*2*3.14)/
           180]^2)) - 150}, {i, 0, 270, 5}, {j, 0, 270, 5}], 1]]
```

Meanwhile, for this example, how about [Plot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot3D.html) instead:

```
Plot3D[(150*(Sin[((i - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)*(Sin[((j - 45)*2*3.14)/
        180]^2)) - 150, {i, 0, 270}, {j, 0, 270}]
```

Comment: I don't care for the syntax in the penultimate example.  Wouldn't `Join @@` be far more clear?